# How can i specify encode in fwrite() for export csv file R?

Tags: r, fwrite

Since **`fwrite()` cannot apply encoding argument** , how can i export csv file in specific encode as fast as `fwrite()` ? (`fwrite()` is the fastest function within my acknowledgement so far)

```
fwrite(DT,"DT.csv",encoding = "UTF-8")
Error in fwrite(DT, "DT.csv", encoding = "UTF-8") : 
  unused argument (encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Comment: As of 2019-March, this is an open issue on the package.  See https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1770

Comment: So , in window , only way to 100% ensure exported file be automatically as UTF-8 in excel is -- write.csv(df, "test.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-8") -- slower processing time trade off fwrite() speed as fwrite() just guessing certain of rows of whole big dataset. Actually user2554330 solution doesn't solve this topics .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should post a reproducible example, but I would guess you could do this by making sure the data in `DT` is in UTF-8 within R, then setting the encoding of each column to "unknown".  R will then assume the data is encoded in the native encoding when you write it out.

For example,

```
DF <- data.frame(text = "á", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
DF$text <- enc2utf8(DF$text) # Only necessary if Encoding(DF$text) isn't "UTF-8"
Encoding(DF$text) <- "unknown"
data.table::fwrite(DF, "DF.csv", bom = TRUE)
```

If the columns of `DF` are factors, you'll need to convert them to character vectors before this will work.

Answer (score 7):

As of writing this, fwrite does not support forcing encoding.  There is a workaround that I use, but it's a bit more obtuse than I'd like. For your example:

```
readr::write_excel_csv(DT[,0],"DT.csv")
data.table::fwrite(DT,file = "DT.csv",append = T)
```

The first line will save only the headers of your data table to the CSV, defaulting to UTF-8 with the Byte order mark required to let Excel know that the file is encoded UTF-8.  The **fwrite** statement then uses the append option to add additional lines to the original CSV.  This retains the encoding from **write_excel_csv**, while maximizing the write speed.

Comment: Works, but the `readr::write_delim` command selects the wrong dimension of the data.table. It should rather be `readr::write_excel_csv(DT[0,],"DT.csv")`

Answer (score 2):

If you work within R,
try this as working approach:

```r
# You have DT   
# DT is a data.table / data.frame   
# DT$text contains any text data not encoded with 'utf-8'       

library(data.table)   
DT$text <– enc2utf8(DT$text) # it forces underlying data to be encoded with 'utf-8'   
fwrite(DT, "DT.csv", bom = T) # Then save the file using ' bom = TRUE '
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I know some people have already answered but I wanted to contribute a more holistic solution using the answer from user2554330.

```
# Encode data in UTF-8
for (col in colnames(DT)) {
    names(DT) <- enc2utf8(names(DT)) # Column names need to be encoded too
    DT[[col]] <- as.character(DT[[col]]) # Allows for enc2utf8() and Encoding()
    DT[[col]] <- enc2utf8(DT[[col]]) # same as users' answer
    Encoding(DT[[col]]) <- "unknown"
}

fwrite(DT, "DT.csv", bom = T)

# When re-importing your data be sure to use encoding = "UTF-8"
DT2 <- fread("DT.csv", encoding = "UTF-8") 
# DT2 should be identical to the original DT
```

This should work for any and all UTF-8 characters anywhere on a data.table